# using proxy failed for checking cipher suit error PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR on blocked host

Tags: go, ssl, https, proxy

I am trying to build a HTTPS proxy But i get `PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR` in firefox that means failed to create a secure connection because no cipher suit found ([more description](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/pr_end_of_file_error)).
What I do is after receiving `CONNECT` header from browser, I make a socket to that host, Connect successfully, and then write `HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established\r\n\r\n` to broswer and then just pipe each other. It works OK on some host like google but not on blocked host (in my country) like youtube. I even changed DNS to 8.8.8.8 (google) but still doesn't work. I think that browser tries to get something out of proxy but don't know what or how.

```golang
func main() {
ln, _ := net.Listen("tcp", ":"+jjConfig.ListenPort)

    for {
        conn, _ := ln.Accept()
        err = conn.SetDeadline(time.Time{})
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
        fmt.Println("Connection Received")
        go handleSocket(conn)
    }
}

func handleSocket(client_to_proxy net.Conn) {
    buffer := make([]byte, 9*1024)
    length, err := bufio.NewReader(client_to_proxy).Read(buffer)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("ERR1 ", err)
        return
    }

    message := processReceived(buffer, length, jjConfig.ListenAuthentication, jjConfig.ListenUsers,
        jjConfig.ListenEncryption, jjConfig.ListenEncryptionKey)
    if message == "" {
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("MESSAGE IS: " + message)

    var host []string
    headers := strings.Split(message, "\r\n")
    for _, header := range headers {
        if strings.HasPrefix(header, "Host") {
            host = strings.Split(header, " ")
            fmt.Println("HOST ISSSSSSSS:" + host[1])
            break
        }
    }

    if strings.HasSuffix(host[1], "443") {
        proxy_to_server, e := net.Dial("tcp", host[1])
        if e != nil {
            fmt.Println("ERROR3 ", e)
            return
        }

        fmt.Println("CONNECTED TO: " + host[1])

        Writelength, err := client_to_proxy.Write([]byte("HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established\r\n\r\n"))
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
        fmt.Println("WROTE 200 OK: " + strconv.Itoa(Writelength))
        if e != nil {
            fmt.Println("ERROR4 ", e)
            return
        }

        go exchange(client_to_proxy, proxy_to_server, host[1])
        exchange(proxy_to_server, client_to_proxy, host[1])

    } else {
        proxy_to_server, e := net.Dial("tcp", host[1]+":80")
        if e != nil {
            fmt.Println("ERROR5 ", e)
            return
        }
        Writelength, e := proxy_to_server.Write([]byte(message))
        fmt.Println("WROTE 80 Header: " + strconv.Itoa(Writelength))
        if e != nil {
            fmt.Println("ERROR6 ", e)
            return
        }

        go exchange(proxy_to_server, client_to_proxy, host[1])
        exchange(client_to_proxy, proxy_to_server, host[1])
    }
}

func exchange(src, dest net.Conn, host string) {
    defer func(src net.Conn) {
        err := src.Close()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("ERRCPP2 ", err)
        }
    }(src)
    defer func(dest net.Conn) {
        err := dest.Close()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("ERRCPP1 ", err)
        }
    }(dest)
    written, err := io.Copy(src, dest)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("COPY ERROR SERVER IS "+host+": ", written, err)
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the code you provide is not sufficiently complete. It cannot be used to reproduce the problem, it cannot even be used to understand how you read the request  - it just magically shows up in `message` in your code. The processing itself is strange though, i.e. you don't extract the target given from CONNECT but instead from the Host header. Also PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR just means that the connection unexpectedly broke and is not  primarily related to ciphers. It might just the the GCW your are behind detects the access and blocks it.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich complete code is here https://github.com/khordady/goroxy . SO doesn't let insert so much code. I use ```Host``` because sometimes host is different than ```Connect``` url and ```Host``` is more accurate(specially in HTTP). for example Connect url was example.com/xyz/file.css and Host was example.com or evenexample2.com for distribution traffic. I update the code

Comment: *"for example Connect url was example.com/xyz/file.css"* - a CONNECT request has only `host:port`, not the path as target. The Host header is irrelevant for a CONNECT request. For the other requests (GET, ...) a proxy request contains after the method the full URL, i.e. `http://host/path`. Thus, everything is in the [request-line](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1.1)

Comment: *" SO doesn't let insert so much code."* - for a reason. The point is that you should [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), i.e. reduce the code you have to the essentials which still show the problem. This helps to focus on what is really the problem and not being faced with a larger code base and thus discouraged to help. Consider that you expect others to invest their time and knowledge for free to help you - so it is up to you to make it easy for others to help.